# Mostrar tabela apenas se tiver elementos em angular 2+

Tags: angularjs, angular

Tenho a seguinte tabela:

```
    <table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Nome</td>
      <td>Email</td>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Status</td>
      <td width=275 align="center">Ação</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr *ngFor="let ticket of tickets">
        <td>{{ticket.nome}}</td>
        <td>{{ticket.email}}</td>
        <td>{{ticket.data | date:'dd/mM/yyyy'}}</td>
        <td *ngIf="ticket.status == 1">Aberto</td>
        <td *ngIf="ticket.status == 2">Em Andamento</td>
        <td *ngIf="ticket.status == 3">Fechado</td>
        <td width=275>
            <a class="btn btn-info" routerLink="/show/{{ticket.id}}">Detalhes</a>
            <a class="btn btn-success" routerLink="/edit/{{ticket.id}}">Editar</a>
            <a class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteTickets(ticket.id)">Deletar</a>
        </td>
     </tr>

  </tbody>

</table>
```

Tentei algo como:

```
 <div class="col-xs-12" *ngIf="tickets.length === 0">
        <p>
          Não há tickets! Comece por <a [routerLink]="['/add']">aqui</a> !
        </p>

      </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 table-responsive" *ngIf="tickets.length > 0">
```

Deste modo ele esconde quando não há tickets cadastrados, mas não mostra a mensagem do `<p>` e quando clico em "Excluir Ticket", tenho que dar refresh na página para atualizar.
Como posso corrigir isso?

Comment: se você utilizar o `ngIf` com 2 `=` não funciona?

Comment: `*ngIf="tickets.length == 0"`

Comment: não aparece a mensagem que eu colocar no <p>, e quando eu clico pra excluir o ticket tenho que dar refresh, mesma coisa com 3 ===

Comment: @Leticia fiz um teste em [stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jbxd6m?ctl=1&embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts&hideExplorer=1) e funciona.